# Memory keeps getting up during Threading with Python

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, memory

I have a problem with Threading in Python. The Memory keeps getting up (pythonw.exe).. it starts with +- 20.000 kB, but keeps rising untill the programm is finished. Anyone knows how to fix this?

```
class Threads(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        try:
            HTML = urllib2.urlopen(//URL//).read()
        except urllib2.HTTPError: pass
        except: pass

def __Scan__():
    Count = 0
    while Count <10000:
        Count = Count + 1
        try:
            Thread = Threads()
            Thread.name = Count
            Thread.start()
        except:
            Count = Count - 1
```

Each Thread will open an URL, and then I store the number of the Thread in a list. But I don't think thats the cause of the rising memory? Anyone can help?

Thx

Comment: what are you trying to? better look at the multiprocessing module of Python

Comment: And you are starting tons of new Threads without handling their proper terminatiom

Answer (score 1):

The increase in memory is likely from the stack space created for each new thread. Threads in Python (and most other languages) have a certain amount of resource overhead. Each time you create one, a little bit of memory is allocated for it.

Comment: Plus, he is creating 10000 threads, how would that go without memory usage increasing?

Comment: I supposed that while creating new threads, the old ones would be done. So I thought the Memory should stay atleast proximately at the same level.

Comment: You would need to call `join` on each thread for the resources to be reclaimed.

Comment: That works... but it slows this process a lot... It first did 1000 URLS in 2 sec's, with the join() method it takes over 1 minute..

Comment: Look into multiprocessing.Pool()

Comment: @jknupp You don't have to call `join` on a thread to reclaim its resources! It'll terminate as soon as the `run` method finishes! Also while creation of new threads isn't cheap, it's still *much* faster than actually getting data from a webserver, hence all 1000 threads will exist at the same time. The obvious solution is to use a threadpool here.

Comment: @Voo you're right; mental lapse on my part (I'm sure I essentially made his process run serially with the `join` calls). The cause of the issue remains the same, though. And I'm almost positive the cPython interpreter doesn't return heap allocated resources obtained during thread creation. A threadpool is indeed the correct approach.

Comment: @jknupp "I'm almost positive the cPython interpreter doesn't return heap allocated resources obtained during thread creation" - what do you mean? I doubt CPython is leaking memory during thread creation - that would be quite the bug.

Comment: @Voo It's not leaking memory in the sense that the memory is allocated but not reachable. Rather, it manages its own memory (see [the docs here](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/memory.html). Raw `malloc` calls are only done by the Memory Manager; likewise with free. A quick test (loop indefinitely and check memory usage vs create 1000 threads that immediately finish and check memory usage) confirms that the interpreter is not returning the memory to the OS, which makes sense.

Comment: @jknupp Memory allocated with `malloc` is generally not returned to the OS when freed (glibc only does it for large enough memory regions that it allocated with `mmap`). But that doesn't really qualify as a "leak".

Comment: @Voo Sorry, I should have been more precise. I didn't mean literally returning memory to the OS like a `brk` call would do. I just meant calling `free` vs. keeping allocated then "logically" `free`'d memory in a process specific memory pool. To the user, both use the same amount of resources.